# Bounds on expectation of Gaussian random vectors

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, expected-value

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $n\geq m$, be independent standard Gaussian random vectors and define $D\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, a positive-definite (symmetric) matrix.

I want to prove that 
$$
-E\|X\|_2+E\|Y\|_2\leq -\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}\quad\quad (\text{1})
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{E\|\sqrt{D}Y\|_2}{\sqrt{tr(D)}}\leq \dfrac{E\|Y\|_2}{\sqrt{m}}\quad\quad (\text{2})
$$

(Here $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{x^{T}x}$, $tr(D)$ is the trace of $D$ and $\sqrt{D}$ is such that $(\sqrt{D})^2=D$.)

For (1) I know by Jensen's inequality that $E\|X\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}$ and $E\|Y\|_2\leq \sqrt{m}$. But how this implies (1)?

For (2) I know (again by Jensen) that $E\|\sqrt{D}Y\|_2\leq \sqrt{tr(D)}$ but that doesn't help me to obtain the bound since $E\|Y\|_2/\sqrt{m}\leq 1$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice questions, can you share where you got them from?

For the second one:

We can show this claim by showing that the right side is maximized for $D = I$.

$$\frac{E ||\sqrt D Y||_2}{\sqrt{tr(D)}}=E||\sqrt{\frac{D}{tr(D)}}Y||_2$$

The expectation of the norm and the expectation of the norm squared are both maximized by the same $D$ since squaring is monotonic for positive values. So we can instead maximize:

$$E||\sqrt{\frac{D}{tr(D)}}Y||_2^2$$

It's not too hard to show that this expression is convex is $D$ by showing the hessian is positive semidefinite. We can then show that the maximum is attained for $D = I$ by showing that the gradient is $0$ at that point:

$$\nabla_D E||\sqrt{\frac{D}{tr(D)}}Y||_2^2=E[\frac{YY^T}{tr(D)} - \frac{Y^TDY}{tr(D)^2}I]$$

Applying $E[YY^T] = I$ and $E[Y^TDY] = tr(D)$ shows that this is $0$ for $D = I$, and thus the claim holds.

I also tried another way by expressing the ratio in terms of the SVD of $D$. Then you end up with something like this for the ratio on the left:

$$E ||\sum_i \alpha_i \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_j \lambda_j}}v_i||$$

where $\alpha_i$ is the length of the projection of $Y$ onto the eigenvector $v_i$ of $D$. And on the right you get:

$$E ||\sum_i \alpha_i \frac{1}{\sqrt m}v_i||$$

You can then show that the first expression is maximized when all $\lambda_i$ are equal. wlog, since $V$ (the matrix of eigenvectors) is orthonormal, this shows that this expression is maximized for $D=I$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it out as soon as possible. The reference is very interesting (at least for me). I took it from the book "High-Dimensional Statistics: a Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint" from MJ Wainwright. You can find these two inequalities in the appendix of chapter 6, which corresponds to the completion of the proof of Theorem 6.1. The whole topic is about concentration of the norm of Gaussian random matrices. These were the only steps of the proof that I couldn't get.

Comment: Oh very cool, I'm also working through the same textbook (but focusing more directly on John Duchi's Stat300b course). Thanks!

Comment: I took a glance at the syllabus of the course you mentioned. If you are involved in those topics I highly recommend the lecture notes of Emilien Joly http://joly415.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Cours/v.0.9.pdf. It can be a good complement to that course.

Comment: Why you claim that $\phi(a,b)$ is concave since $\phi(0,b)$ is convex?

Comment: I'll go through this again when i get a chance, but it looks like you're right. This one really is tricky!

Comment: The first thing i will check is if this is concave for a, b > 0 (strict inequality). Since the X and Y are equal to 0 with probability 0, this shouldnt be an issue for this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work. I already made the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645660/concavity-of-the-difference-of-square-roots.

Comment: Ah that's right, I was recalling Sylvester's criterion for negative definite matrices incorrectly. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: The first claim is interesting since it's basically a claim about how close the bound from Jensen's inequality is in higher dimensions: $\sqrt n - E\|X\| \leq \sqrt m -E\|Y\|$.

Comment: You can try to solve just for $n=m+1$ (that is sufficient) and use the convexity of $x\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+c}$ with conditional expectation and Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This was done with the help of a friend.

For the first one. It is sufficient to prove it for $n=m+1$. Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of iid $N(0,1)$ and let $Z=\sum_{j=1}^mX_j^2$.

It's easy to see that the functions 
$$
x\mapsto \sqrt{c+x^2},\;c\geq 0,\quad x\mapsto\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}
$$
are convex in $[0,\infty)$ (by double derivative if you will). Therefore, by Jensen inequality,
\begin{align*}
E\sqrt{Z+X^2_{m+1}}-E\sqrt{Z}&=E\left[E\left[\sqrt{Z+X^2_{m+1}}\,\Big|\,Z\right]\right]-E\sqrt{Z}\\
&\geq E\left[\sqrt{Z+E[X^2_{m+1}|Z]}\right]-E\sqrt{Z}\\
&=E\left[\sqrt{Z+1}\right]-E\sqrt{Z}\\
&=E[\sqrt{Z+1}-\sqrt{Z}]\\
&\geq \sqrt{EZ+1}-\sqrt{EZ}\\
&=\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your argument is actually not correct. If you use Jensen's inequality correctly, you should get $E \sqrt{Z+X_{m+1}^2} \geq E_Z  \sqrt{Z+ (E_{X_{m+1}} X_{m+1})^2} = E \sqrt{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

I leave a link to [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4330706) to the first question for those who stumbled upon the same problem.